# Unable to select a result from drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am new to this and i am trying to write a script where it will query the DB and return all the usernames in a drop down list and then to copy out the selected name and then when you register a Dog to them it will copy the name into the DB, 
So Owners can have many dogs but dog can only have 1 owner...
i can enter Name and Breed but not the results from the drop down list,
i did try to get java script to pull the selected item in drop down to be where the $ownername is in in the 'insert into...' script

can you send me a message if you can help me with this i will link you the files to download

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `dog`(`id`, `dogname`, `breed`, `owner`)
 VALUES  ('', '$reg_dogname', '$breed', '$row');") or die (mysql_error());
     $userid = mysql_insert_id();

}}


$sql = mysql_query('SELECT `username` FROM  `users`');
$ownername = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $ownername[] = $row;
```

---

```
 <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="selectDropdown()">
  <?php
  foreach ($ownername as $ownername1) {
  ?> 
  <option value="<?php echo $ownername1['username']?>">
    <?php echo $ownername1['username']?>
    </option>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: Please post the offending code here. We don't often like to go to an external site to view it, and especially are not likely to download an archive which has to be unzipped and read locally.

Comment: Can you please share you `selectDropdown()` code?

Comment: Is there some particular part of this that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Hi, the zip is clean it is just the php file zipped :)

Code i have issues with is 

 <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="selectDropdown()">
  <?php
  foreach ($ownername as $ownername1) {
  ?> 
  <option value="<?php echo $ownername1['username']?>">
 <?php echo $ownername1['username']?>
    </option>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </select> 
             
0---
and 


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `dog`(`id`, `dogname`, `breed`, `owner`)
 VALUES  ('', '$reg_dogname', '$breed', '$row');") or die (mysql_error());
     $userid = mysql_insert_id();
  
}}

Comment: $sql = mysql_query('SELECT `username` FROM  `users`');
$ownername = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $ownername[] = $row;

Comment: It would be easier to read if you added that code to the question instead of in the comments.

Comment: Sorry very new... give me a second.. :)

Comment: "Code i have issues with is […]" What issues exactly? I don't get where your problem is.

Comment: when the drop down brings the usersnames from the other table and puts them into the drop down list i am unable to use the selected value from the drop down and then insert it into the 'dogs' table because each dog needs a owner but each owner can have many dogs... 
i wrote half of this on Access and it worked only when moving from access to writing it again in php and html is when i get issues.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to give you a problem specific answer until you post your code, but I think this would work pretty well for you:

-create relational tables for owners, breeds, and dogs:

```
Table: owners
Fields:
id_key: integer, auto number, primary key - table index
owner: varchar, 16 character, unique index - account records (unique prevents duplicate account records)
password: varchar, 32 character (assuming you are using md5 encryption, you will always get a 32 character result. Additional security concerns are beyond the scope of this question)
any other account related fields (but not dogs, give them their own table)

Table: breeds
Fields:
id_key: integer, auto number, primary key - table index
breed: varchar, 16 character, unique - available dog breeds

Table: dogs
Fields:
id_key: integer, auto number, primary key - table index
dog: varchar, 16 character, index - dog owned by account
breed: varchar, 32 character, index, foreign key= breeds.breed on delete=restrict on update=cascade (prevents duplicate breed entries during data entry)
owner: varchar, 16 character, index, foreign key= owners.owner on delete=cascade on update=cascade (this constricts the dog owner to existing accounts)
```

Then make a form something like this:

```
<?php
$formdata=array(
    owners => array(),
    breeds => array()
);
require_once 'dbconnection.php';
echo '<form id="dog_input" name="dog_input" method="post">';
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `owner` FROM owners;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    array_push($formdata[owners], $row[0]);
}
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `breed` FROM breeds;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    array_push($formdata[breeds], $row[0]);
}
?>
<FORM name="dog_input" method="post" action="dog_data.php">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="owner">Dog Owner</label>
            <SELECT name="owner" id="owner">
            <?php
                foreach ($formdata[owners] as $i) {
                    echo '<OPTION>'.$i.'</OPTION>';
                >
            ?>
            </SELECT>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="breed">Dog Breed</label>
            <SELECT name="breed" id="breed">
            <?php
                foreach ($formdata[breeds] as $i) {
                    echo '<OPTION>'.$i.'</OPTION>';
                >
            ?>
            </SELECT>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="dog">Dog Name</label>
            <INPUT type="text" name="dog" />
        </li>
        <li><INPUT type="submit" value="Submit /></li>
    </ul>
</FORM>
```

Then you need to create the validation script that will check your results and enter safe data into the database:

```
<?php
    /*
    * dog_data.php - checks data and inserts it into the database.
    */
    require_once 'dbconnection.php';
    $owner = $_POST['owner'];
    $breed = $_POST['breed'];
    $dog = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['owner']);
    //perform any additional data validation here, use an if statement to check validation before insert query if you do so
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `dogs` (`id_key`, `owner`, `breed`, `dog`)
                 VALUES(DEFAULT, '".$owner."', '".$breed."', '".$dog."');");
    mysql_close($con);
    header(" Location: http://www.example-redirection-page.com");
?>
```

Comment: I broke my example, gimme a sec to fix it please.